# fastest & efficent MarkDown in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, markdown

I'm looking for a JavaScript MarkDown (MD) engine, for both in-browser & server-side via node.js.  Most of the time, the intended output will be HTML5 (though I may use MD for XML, PDF, & the various ePub formats; uncertain if direct MD to xxx-format or HTML to xxx-format would be best).  Fast conversion of a large MD file would be best, but I'm also planning to use it on lower-end mobile phones, so memory usage is also to be considered.

I imagine there is JavaScript-MD experience out there that I can't find, tests people have run, etc.  So far here is the information I have collected:

https://github.com/chjj/marked "Built for speed"

https://github.com/guybrush/showdown  Older & no longer maintained

Other research, most older:
[What is the Best JQuery WYSIWYM Textile Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430175/what-is-the-best-jquery-wysiwym-textile-editor)

[Markdown to convert double asterisks to bold text in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168285/markdown-to-convert-double-asterisks-to-bold-text-in-javascript/10168521#10168521)

[Javascript to convert Markdown/Textile to HTML (and, ideally, back to Markdown/Textile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319657/javascript-to-convert-markdown-textile-to-html-and-ideally-back-to-markdown-t)

[Is there any good Markdown Javascript library or control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134235/is-there-any-good-markdown-javascript-library-or-control)

[How would you go about parsing Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605434/how-would-you-go-about-parsing-markdown)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35084

Comment: Seems that https://github.com/chjj/marked keeps up with speed tests on occasion.

BTW, not sure why this was closed?  It is an unique question (eg fastest & (most) efficient), which is not strictly covered by the previous SO questions.   I had conducted research, & was looking for other perspectives & proofs.

Comment: Please check out the [Rho](http://npmjs.org/package/rho) project. Although it's not 100% compatible with Markdown, you may still find it very attractive due to its performance, asynchronous rendering and highly anticipated syntax for `id` and `class` attributes.

Comment: @incarnate that looks pretty sweet, how come people are still using Markdown? :O