# Updating the text in a contentEditable field while the user is typing

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, richtext

I am trying to build a WYSIWYG markdown editor using a `<div>` with the `contentEditable` attribute.

Each time a `keyup` event fires, I am using `str.replace` with a regular expression to find instances of markdown syntax. For example, in the string "`this text is **bold**`", I use HTML to make the text appear bold in real-time.

However, on each key press and update of the "pseudo-field", the caret/cursor returns to the start. I have tried various strategies to reposition it, including `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`, but it seems these attributes are not applicable to a `<div>` (they are undefined).

```
var editor = document.getElementById('editor');

editor.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    var doc = editor.innerHTML;
    editor.innerHTML = doc.replace(/\*\*(\S(.*?\S)?)\*\*/gm, '<strong>$1</strong>');
});
```

(credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31933119/) for the regex.)

**Note:** I am aware there are similar questions already posted on StackOverflow, but the majority were asked 8-10 years ago and use jQuery. I wonder if a more modern, straightforward approach has come about in the last decade that uses vanilla JS.